# Blender FBX Tex problem

Tags: texturing, export

I'm new to blender, but after hours of searching, I'm giving up and asking you guys. I copy the FBX file and tick next to it, but this is what happens when I import it. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Before FBX]

[image: After FBX]

Comment: You haven't actually said what problem you're having!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think his issue that when it auto imports the material it is creating a unique Mapping node for each texture rather than using a single one. Is this something node wrangler is doing or is this your own script?

Comment: @Jakemoyo i think is about node wrangler.

Comment: @JohnEason Hi, my problem is when i export FBX it to fbx file the vector map is multiplied every time. some settings are lost and most importantly it does not process the vector values ​​that I have given as tex.

Comment: I don't know much about FBX import and export in Blender, but from [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#compatibility) it seems that quite a lot may not be supported yet.

Comment: @JohnEason i understand my problem now. thank you.